# Proper way to call JNDI datasource within Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I am using a Java web application on a Tomcat server and would like to know what is the "best practice" in terms of accessing a database connection from within Tomcat's JNDI?

Currently this is basically what I am doing each time I need to access the database:

```
Context envContext = null;
DataSource dataSource = null;
try {
    envContext  = (Context)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/datasource");
    return dataSource.getConnection();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}finally {
    if(envContext != null){
        try{
           envContext.close();
        } catch (NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, is this the proper way to look up a connection from JNDI each time I want to access the database? Should I hold a reference to the Context or the Datasource instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jndi lookups are essentially Map lookups so their overhead is minimal. But it is preferable to get the DataSource once and "cache" that. So if anything - writing a method to return the DataSource is ideal so as not to bind too much code to J2EE internals and make code easier to test.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you. Another question, is there much overhead in creating a new Context each time I'm doing data access?

Comment: Relatively speaking - I don't believe so. But if you bechmarked it and created a Context everytime vs just caching the datasource - I'd suspect you'd see a  difference. But practically speaking - the number of times you get a DataSource (or Context) is minimal compared to the rest of the activities in processing a request.

Comment: JNDI lookups are not expensive, `InitialContext` lookups are **VERY EXPENSIVE** in every application container and should only be done once at application start. Most people don't know the difference.

Answer (score 4):

`new InitialContext()` is expensive in every application container, it should be a `static final` and created in a `static {}` block, effectively making it a `Singleton`. You should only have to create this reference once and re-use it everywhere you need it.

`DataSource` should be a `static` as well. You should have a `public static Connection getConnection();` method to retrieve `Connection` objects, the code should never have to deal with `DataSource` directly. This works especially well with `PooledDataSource` implementations.

Comment: Why is it expensive? It doesn't have to do much, and specifically it doesn't have to do any network I/O? I suspect this is urban myth.

Comment: @EJP Not an urban myth, I had a contract where one of the "lead" developers ( a VB person ) was writing Servlets and he was creating `new InitialContext()` on every request. Each request took almost a minute.  He bitched about how slow Java was, blah, blah, blah. I reviewed his code and moved that one line to a `private static final` and boom. Request were in the `hundreds of millisecond` range. This was a very early version of WebLogic so it might not be that bad now because of Moore's Law. But it was a reproducible issue when I wrote this answer in March 2011.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. *Why* is it expensive? and, to quote you from another place, [YEINU: Your experience is not universal](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2014/01/02/yeinu-your-experience-is-not-universal/). Have you actually tested 'every application container'? Without that, your answer is baseless. And how does '`new InitialContext()` is expensive' tally with your comment above that '`InitialContext` *lookups* are **VERY EXPENSIVE**'? Make up your mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this too:-

```
...

Context initContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource");

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lookup code looks ok
In your problem context, caching the datasource seems fine as long as you are not caching the actual connection object.

I haven't used this approach in a while though. These days, at a minimum, I use spring to inject the datasource/initialize JdbcTemplate

Comment: Yeah, normally I would just use some third party utility, like hibernate, but for this, I am not allowed to use anything besides straight java.